# How to send data after switching from one activity to another?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am new to android programming and want to know how I can send data using bluetooth after switching from one activity to another. I have a `MainActivity` which helps in establishing bluetooth connection and on click of a button NEXT, it switches from `MainActivity` to `SecondActivity`,where I wish to enter a string and click on SEND to send the data to another bluetooth device. But whenever I click on SEND,the activity switches back to MainActivity and the data is not sent. How can I do what i intended to do?
Here is my code - 
`MainActivity.java` :

```
package com.example.gumm.illizarov_test;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    Button btnEnableDisable_Discoverable;
    Button next;


    BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;
    Button btnStartConnection;
    TextView incomingMessages;


    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

    BluetoothDevice mBTDevice;

    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();

    public DeviceListAdapter mDeviceListAdapter;

    ListView lvNewDevices;


    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch(state){
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: STATE OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE ON");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING ON");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Broadcast Receiver for changes made to bluetooth states such as:
     * 1) Discoverability mode on/off or expire.
     */
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)) {

                int mode = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                switch (mode) {
                    //Device is in Discoverable Mode
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Enabled.");
                        break;
                    //Device not in discoverable mode
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Able to receive connections.");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Not able to receive connections.");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connecting....");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connected.");
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    };




    /**
     * Broadcast Receiver for listing devices that are not yet paired
     * -Executed by btnDiscover() method.
     */
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ACTION FOUND.");

            if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)){
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra (BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mBTDevices.add(device);
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getName() + ": " + device.getAddress());
                mDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(context, R.layout.device_adapter_view, mBTDevices);
                lvNewDevices.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Broadcast Receiver that detects bond state changes (Pairing status changes)
     */
    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver4 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)){
                BluetoothDevice mDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                //3 cases:
                //case1: bonded already
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDED.");
                    //inside BroadcastReceiver4
                    mBTDevice = mDevice;
                }
                //case2: creating a bone
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_BONDING.");
                }
                //case3: breaking a bond
                if (mDevice.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver: BOND_NONE.");
                }
            }
        }
    };



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: called.");
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1);
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2);
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3);
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4);
        //mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btnONOFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnONOFF);
        btnEnableDisable_Discoverable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDiscoverable_on_off);
        lvNewDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNewDevices);
        mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        btnStartConnection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartConnection);
        incomingMessages = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.btnStartConnection);

        //Broadcasts when bond state changes (ie:pairing)
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver4, filter);

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);


        btnONOFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: enabling/disabling bluetooth.");
                enableDisableBT();
            }
        });

        btnStartConnection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startConnection();
            }
        });



    }


    //create method for starting connection
//***remember the conncction will fail and app will crash if you haven't paired first
    public void startConnection(){
        startBTConnection(mBTDevice,MY_UUID_INSECURE);
    }

    /**
     * starting chat service method
     */
    public void startBTConnection(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid){
        Log.d(TAG, "startBTConnection: Initializing RFCOM Bluetooth Connection.");

        mBluetoothConnection.startClient(device,uuid);
    }



    public void enableDisableBT(){
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: Does not have BT capabilities.");
        }
        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: enabling BT.");
            Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBTIntent);

            IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
        }
        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: disabling BT.");
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

            IntentFilter BTIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, BTIntent);
        }

    }

    public void next(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }


    public void btnEnableDisable_Discoverable(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "btnEnableDisable_Discoverable: Making device discoverable for 300 seconds.");

        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver2,intentFilter);

    }



    public void btnDiscover(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Looking for unpaired devices.");

        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.d(TAG, "btnDiscover: Canceling discovery.");

            //check BT permissions in manifest
            checkBTPermissions();

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
        }
        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){

            //check BT permissions in manifest
            checkBTPermissions();

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter discoverDevicesIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3, discoverDevicesIntent);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is required for all devices running API23+
     * Android must programmatically check the permissions for bluetooth. Putting the proper permissions
     * in the manifest is not enough.
     *
     * NOTE: This will only execute on versions > LOLLIPOP because it is not needed otherwise.
     */
    private void checkBTPermissions() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            int permissionCheck = this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
            permissionCheck += this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
            if (permissionCheck != 0) {

                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001); //Any number
            }
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "checkBTPermissions: No need to check permissions. SDK version < M.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        //first cancel discovery because its very memory intensive.
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on a device.");
        String deviceName = mBTDevices.get(i).getName();
        String deviceAddress = mBTDevices.get(i).getAddress();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceName = " + deviceName);
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceAddress = " + deviceAddress);

        //create the bond.
        //NOTE: Requires API 17+? I think this is JellyBean
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to pair with " + deviceName);
            mBTDevices.get(i).createBond();

            mBTDevice = mBTDevices.get(i);
            mBluetoothConnection = new BluetoothConnectionService(MainActivity.this);
        }
    }


}
```

SecondActivity.java:

```
package com.example.gumm.illizarov_test;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    Button send;
    EditText etSend;
    TextView incomingMessages;
    StringBuilder messages;
    BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        etSend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        incomingMessages = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.incomingMessage);
        messages = new StringBuilder();
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }


    public void send(View view) {

            byte[] bytes = etSend.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
            mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);

            etSend.setText("");

    }
}
```

BluetoothConnectionService.java:

```
package com.example.gumm.illizarov_test;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.UUID;



public class BluetoothConnectionService {
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothConnectionServ";

    private static final String appName = "MYAPP";

    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

    private final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    Context mContext;

    private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;

    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private UUID deviceUUID;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

    public BluetoothConnectionService(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        start();
    }


    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
     * (or until cancelled).
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {

        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

        public AcceptThread(){
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try{
                tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(appName, MY_UUID_INSECURE);

                Log.d(TAG, "AcceptThread: Setting up Server using: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }

            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run(){
            Log.d(TAG, "run: AcceptThread Running.");

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            try{
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket start.....");

                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();

                Log.d(TAG, "run: RFCOM server socket accepted connection.");

            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "AcceptThread: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
            }


            if(socket != null){
                connected(socket,mmDevice);
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread ");
        }

        public void cancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Canceling AcceptThread.");
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "cancel: Close of AcceptThread ServerSocket failed. " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: started.");
            mmDevice = device;
            deviceUUID = uuid;
        }

        public void run(){
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            Log.i(TAG, "RUN mConnectThread ");

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Trying to create InsecureRfcommSocket using UUID: "
                        +MY_UUID_INSECURE );
                tmp = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread: Could not create InsecureRfcommSocket " + e.getMessage());
            }

            mmSocket = tmp;

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket

            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();

                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread connected.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: Closed Socket.");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "mConnectThread: run: Unable to close connection in socket " + e1.getMessage());
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread: Could not connect to UUID: " + MY_UUID_INSECURE );
            }


            connected(mmSocket,mmDevice);
        }
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Closing Client Socket.");
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "cancel: close() of mmSocket in Connectthread failed. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }



    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     AcceptThread starts and sits waiting for a connection.
     Then ConnectThread starts and attempts to make a connection with the other devices AcceptThread.
     **/

    public void startClient(BluetoothDevice device,UUID uuid){
        Log.d(TAG, "startClient: Started.");

        //initprogress dialog
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext,"Connecting Bluetooth"
                ,"Please Wait...",true);

        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, uuid);
        mConnectThread.start();
    }

    /**
     Finally the ConnectedThread which is responsible for maintaining the BTConnection, Sending the data, and
     receiving incoming data through input/output streams respectively.
     **/
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ConnectedThread: Starting.");

            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            //dismiss the progressdialog when connection is established
            try{
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                tmpIn = mmSocket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream

            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                // Read from the InputStream
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);

                    Intent incomingMessageIntent = new Intent("incomingMessage");
                    incomingMessageIntent.putExtra("theMessage",incomingMessage);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(incomingMessageIntent);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            String text = new String(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
            Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputstream: " + text);
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to output stream. " + e.getMessage() );
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    private void connected(BluetoothSocket mmSocket, BluetoothDevice mmDevice) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connected: Starting.");

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     *
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;

        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        Log.d(TAG, "write: Write Called.");
        //perform the write
        mConnectedThread.write(out);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can try to Broadcast your data and listen for it in the second activity. Refer this link, [LocalBroadcastManager] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to use same BluetoothConnectionService object in MainActivity and SecondActivity. I suggested you can use the [Singleton Pattern](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-make-the-perfect-singleton-de6b951dfdb0) to create BluetoothConnectionService.

When you create BluetoothConnectionService Singleton you can switch the MainActivity, SecondActivity and send the data on the same BluetoothConnectionService object.

Here is a simple example. You can refer to it.

BluetoothConnectionService.java

```
public class BluetoothConnectionService {
    // ...
    private static class InstanceHolder {
        private static final BluetoothConnectionService INSTANCE = new BluetoothConnectionService();
    }

    public static BluetoothConnectionService getInstance() {
        return InstanceHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private BluetoothConnectionService() {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        start();
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    // ...
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    private BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;

    public void startBTConnection(BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid){
        Log.d(TAG, "startBTConnection: Initializing RFCOM Bluetooth Connection.");
        if (mBluetoothConnection != null) {
            // connect client
            mBluetoothConnection.startClient(device, uuid);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        // ...
        //create the bond.
        //NOTE: Requires API 17+? I think this is JellyBean
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
            // ...

            // get the BluetoothConnectionService instance
            mBluetoothConnection = BluetoothConnectionService.getInstance();

            // need to set Context to use ProgressDialog.
            mBluetoothConnection.setContext(getApplicationContext());
        }
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // ...
    BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        // ...

        // get the BluetoothConnectionService instance
        mBluetoothConnection = BluetoothConnectionService.getInstance();
    }

    public void send() {
        // ...
        mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have made it work, although I have edited the code a little.

Answer (score 0):

**when intent to**

current activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("count", "1");
startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity:

```
String count= "" ;
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle!= null){
count= bundle.getString("backToMain","0");
}
```